# Creating and naming links using start and end nodes from .shp file

Tags: netlogo

The attribute table of the .shp file has the following format:

```
street_name  start_node  end_node

street_1     A           B
street_1     B           C
street_2     B           D
```

How could I create links using the start and end nodes and then assign to each link the street name associated with its start and end node. For example, the link with start node A and end node B should get the name "street_1" and the street with start node B and end node D should get the name "street_2".

I used foreach `gis:feature-list-of` to link the nodes of the dataset but this way I cannot name the links based on their start and end nodes because some of the nodes are shared between street segments.

Many thanks.

**Edit:**

The columns of the attribute table I am interested in are name1, startNode, and endNode. I have already connected the nodes using the code below and I now have a fully connected road network. I am unsure how I could integrate your code so as the links between the nodes will get the name associated with the combination of nodes that form that link.

```
foreach gis:feature-list-of roads-dataset [ vector-feature ->
    foreach  gis:vertex-lists-of vector-feature [ vertex ->
      let previous-turtle nobody
      foreach vertex [point ->
        let location gis:location-of point
        if not empty? location
        [
          let x item 0 location
          let y item 1 location
          let current-node one-of (turtles-on patch x y) with [ xcor = x and ycor = y ]
          if current-node = nobody [
            create-nodes 1 [
              setxy x y
              set size 0.2
              set shape "circle"
              set color black
              set hidden? true
              set name gis:property-value vector-feature "name1"
              set current-node self
            ]
          ]
          ask current-node [
            if is-turtle? previous-turtle [
              create-link-with previous-turtle
            ]
            set previous-turtle self
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying that your nodes are now correctly named in your model? If that's the case, here's a simplified version of an approach that may work for you. I will note that this is not a very efficient way to go about this as it loops through your links and your attribute table, so if you have many many links it will take a while. To start out with, since I don't have your shapefile, I have made a version of your links example:

```
extensions [csv]

globals [ whole-file ]
turtles-own [ node ]
links-own [ name ]

to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
  let names [ "A" "B" "C" "D" ]
  let n 0
  crt 4 [
   setxy random 30 - 15 random 30 - 15
   set node item n names
   set n n + 1
  ] 

  ask turtles with [ node = "A" ] [
    create-links-to turtles with [node = "B" ]
  ]
  ask turtles with [ node = "B" ] [
    create-links-to turtles with [ node = "C" or node = "D" ]
  ]
end
```

That just builds four turtles, with links as indicated in your example shapefile attribute table. I'm using a file called "node_example.csv" that looks like this:

```
  street_name start_node end_node
1    street_1          A        B
2    street_1          B        C
3    street_2          B        D
```

with four columns, where the first is the observation number.

Essentially, the approach is to iterate through the list and pull out the names of the nodes, from `end1` to `end2` and vice versa (since `both-ends` would pull them in a random order), and compare them to each `start_node` and `end_node` combination in the table. If they match, assign the `street_name` from that row to the link with the match:

```
to link-name 

  set whole-file csv:from-file "node_example.csv"

  foreach sort links [
    [ i ] ->
    show i
    let way-1 list ( [node] of [end1] of i ) ( [node] of [end2] of i )
    let way-2 list ( [node] of [end2] of i ) ( [node] of [end1] of i )
    foreach whole-file [
      [j] ->
      if sublist j 2 4 = way-1 or sublist j 2 4 = way-2 [
        ask i [
          set name item 1 j
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]

  ask links [
    print name
    print (word [node] of end1 [node] of end2 )
  ]

end
```

Obviously, this is predicated on your nodes being named in your model (in this example, the variable used is `node`)- if that's not the case this won't work.

**Edit 1**

Ok, I played around a little using your shapefile. This is not perfect yet, and I can't work on it any more for a while, but maybe it will get you started. Using this setup:

```
extensions [gis]

breed [ nodes node ]
globals [ roads-dataset ]
turtles-own [ name line-start line-end]
links-own [ lname ]
```

My idea is to assign the start and end node names to each point along the line feature, so that the links can check against the feature list. More specific notes in comments, but I've basically modified your gis-feature-node code to do that. Play around with it a bit (takes a while to run) and you'll see there are gaps that I haven't quite figured out- maybe you can make progress.

```
to gis-feature-node
  set roads-dataset gis:load-dataset  "road_links.shp"
  foreach gis:feature-list-of roads-dataset [ vector-feature ->

    ; First, grab the names of the starting and ending node for the current 
    ; vector feature in order to assign common names to all nodes within
    ; the feature

    let first-vertex gis:property-value vector-feature "startNode"
    let last-vertex gis:property-value vector-feature "endNode"

    foreach  gis:vertex-lists-of vector-feature [ vertex ->
      let previous-turtle nobody

      foreach vertex [ point ->
        let location gis:location-of point
        if not empty? location
        [
          let x item 0 location
          let y item 1 location
          let current-node one-of (turtles-on patch x y) with [ xcor = x and ycor = y ]
          if current-node = nobody [
            create-nodes 1 [
              setxy x y
              set size 0.05
              set shape "circle"
              set color white
              set hidden? false
              set name gis:property-value vector-feature "name1"

              ; Here you assign the first-vertex and last-vertex of the entire line
              ; to each node
              set line-start first-vertex 
              set line-end last-vertex
              set current-node self 
            ]
          ]
          ask current-node [
            if is-turtle? previous-turtle [
              create-link-with previous-turtle
            ]
            set previous-turtle self
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]

  ask links [ 
    ;; Here is a major slowdown- reiterate through the entire roads-dataset
    ;  and, if the names in "startNode" and "endNode" match, assign the
    ;  value from "name1" to the link currently being created.
    let way-1 list [line-start] of end1 [line-end] of end2 
    let way-2 list [line-end] of end1 [line-start] of end2  
    foreach gis:feature-list-of roads-dataset [ vector-feature-sub ->
      let vector-start gis:property-value vector-feature-sub "startNode"
      let vector-end gis:property-value vector-feature-sub "endNode"
      let start-end list vector-start vector-end

      if way-1 = start-end or way-2 = start-end [
        set lname gis:property-value vector-feature-sub "name1"
      ]
    ]
  ] 

  ask links with [ lname = "Hamilton Place" ] [
    set color red 
    set thickness 0.2
  ]
  ask links with [ lname = "Whitcomb Street" ] [
    set color yellow
    set thickness 0.2
  ]

end
```

**EDIT 2**

The code below is tested and works - problem sorted.

```
    ask links [
    set is-road? true
    ;; Here is a major slowdown- reiterate through the entire roads-dataset
    ;  and, if the names in "startNode" and "endNode" match, assign the
    ;  value from "name1" to the link currently being created.
    let way-1 list [line-start] of end1 [line-end] of end2
    let way-2 list [line-end] of end1 [line-start] of end2
    let way-3 list [ line-start ] of end1 [ line-end ] of end1
    let way-4 list [ line-start ] of end2 [ line-end ] of end2
    foreach gis:feature-list-of roads-dataset [ vector-feature-sub ->
      let vector-start gis:property-value vector-feature-sub "startNode"
      let vector-end gis:property-value vector-feature-sub "endNode"
      let start-end list vector-start vector-end
      let end-start list vector-end vector-start

      if way-1 = start-end or way-2 = start-end or way-3 = start-end or way-4 = start-end [
        set lname gis:property-value vector-feature-sub "name1"
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

Comment: I edited my post and I also uploaded the .shp and other associated files which can be accessed from this shared [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5ReYaf_vfpqaG9KcWJYQllyTmc)

Comment: Ok round two! Have a look and see if that might help

Comment: You bet! I definitely found that it was skipping some segments, and I haven't the time right now to figure out why- but definitely a heads up that (at least for me) it was missing some 1800 or so links out of the ~6000. Maybe with some tweaking it will work completely... good luck!

Comment: I'll have a look. I just checked and there are indeed 2358 links with `lname = 0`. But thank you for the start. It is a way that shows the results I want.

Comment: You bet- if you end up figuring it out completely I'd be interested in hearing how you do it. Cheers!

Comment: Sorted. I added **EDIT 2** to your answer.

Comment: Accepted- very satisfying to see the full-length of the road colored properly. Well done!